# How to get registred element for event listener?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page which has a bunch of nested elements.

`div
 - div
 - - div
 - - - a
 - - - - div
 - - - - - span
 - - - - - - img`

This pattern and variations of it repeats throughout the page.

I'm currently registering for the `a` element doing

```
document.querySelectorAll('.click-aware a').addEventListener('click', myListener);

function myListener(evt) {
  // some logic function goes here
}
```

The thing is, the `evt` object does not contain a reference to the `a` element.

`evt.target` points to the innermost element (in this example the `img`), and both `srcElement` and `toElement` points to it as well.

How do I get the `a` element **without** having to traverse the `evt.path` upwards until I hit the `a`?

**No jQuery allowed**

I'm asking this because sometimes the listener is not attached to the `a` element.

TLDR: How do I get the element that the event listener was registred to?

Comment: It should be referenced by the this keyword

Comment: I can't accept that as an answer, but thanks anyway! I often forget about `this` in Javascript.

Comment: I mean I can't accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: I will add it as an answer then :)

Comment: `addEventListener` is not available on `NodeList`s, which is what `document.querySelectorAll` returns. You'll have to iterate over the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword to get the reference to the element that owns the handler, or the `event.currentTarget` property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

> *Event.currentTarget* Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

the `event.currentTarget` is a better option, because if the handler is defined using an arrow function (es6) instead of a regular old function, then the `this` will refer to the context where the handler function is defined instead.

Comment: "this" is the element that fires the event, not necessarily where the event is attached.

Comment: Fair enough. But you can .bind it when attaching

Comment: What you mean @KeithRousseau?

Comment: I mean that "this" would be e.currentTarget if you just use addEventListener. You would need to use bind like Tiago mentioned. The problem with bind is that you can't remove the event listener after. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Specifying_this_using_bind()

Comment: I think your best solution here is to just walk up the DOM until you find your link. It's a pretty simple helper where you just get parentNode until the classList contains the class you're looking for. Code using "this" can get pretty ugly and difficult to follow since "this" can have so many different meanings in js depending on context.

Comment: @KeithRousseau you are right that `this` will reference the same as e.currentTarget. Can you provide an example of one instance where that value is not the intended one?
according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget it should refer to the element where the listener is attached

Comment: You're right - it actually does give the right element. I still think this is more confusing in most cases though. The case where you couldn't use it and would need to walk the DOM is if you used event delegation for a list of elements.

Comment: Yes :) but that's because in that case you do not want the element where the handler is attached

Comment: Sorry for being late here, thanks both of you for your insights. This means that both `this` and `evt.currentTarget` are valid solutions for me. Thanks!